# py.test import error "- 'config' not found."

Tags: python, flask, pytest

While trying to add py.test functionality to a Flask API I ran into the following error message when calling py.test on my source directory

```
E               ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config'. Possible reasons are:
E               
E               - missing __init__.py in a package;
E               - package or module path not included in sys.path;
E               - duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
E               - missing module, class, function or variable;
E               
E               Debugged import:
E               
E               - 'config' not found.
E               
E               Original exception:
E               
E               ImportError: No module named config
```

The issue seems to stem after I have instantiated my Flask app and try to import the config from config.py (line 5).

```
from flask import Flask

# Setup app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

# Import views
from views import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Everything seems to work accordingly if I manually set the config variables instead of importing them. Has anyone encountered anything like this? I wasn't able to find anything helpful in the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suppose these ones are the most probable

```
E           - package or module path not included in sys.path;
E           - duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
```

So the first thing I'd try is to rename config file to something like `config_default.py`.

Then you can try to use the real object instead of string eg. importing config yourself:

```
from flask import Flask
import config

# Setup app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
```

But most likely you'll face the same error: `ImportError: No module named config`

Also you can use `app.config.from_pyfile()` and specify full path to your config file:

```
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

`from_pyfile()` uses a different technique to create the object (it uses `[exc`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/config.py#L129)).

I myself prefer to use `from_envvar()` and specify which config file to use in launcher (supervisord nowadays).

Comment: Thank you very much! 'from_pyfile('...')' worked like a charm. Thanks corresponding doc as well. Eventually I will be using from_envar(...) but right now I'm still developing the app (no deployment scripts and what have you). Again, thank you!

Comment: `from __future__ import absolute_import` in case you have `myapp.flask.config` or similar.

Comment: I prefer `from_pyfile` better since it doesn't cause error when you are making cross package importing, unlike `from_object`

Comment: In my case - "app.config.from_pyfile" solved my problem.

Answer (score 19):

Although this is an old post and very essential problem of Flask, which I happen to have this these days. In case that anyone also have the same problem, you should check the path of config.py file. At first, I created config.py inside app dir. Then I moved outside the app, it works. Like this:

```
-app---
   |
   |----__init__.py
   |----config.py
```

Change to:

```
-app---
   |
   |----__init__.py
-config.py
```

Answer (score 5):

Twil makes good points and alternatives to app.config.from_object. However, I stumbled upon this question while having trouble with the following [Flask Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms) and I wanted to follow the guide and use from_object.

The way I corrected my issue was that I had originally put the config.py file in my 'app' package. It should reside outside of my app in that same folder from which I had my run.py script.

I hope this answer saves someone a bit of time.

Answer (score 3):

Changing `app.config.from_object(config)` to `app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')` solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just try absolute import instead

```
app.config.from_object(app.config)
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it help someone else, removing the empty `__init__.py` next to `app.py` and `config.py` has resolved my issue.

I was able to continue the usage of: `app.config.from_object('config')`